# Adding ASC/DESC with order by in Phalcon QueryBuilder

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by, phalcon, query-builder

From the Phalcon Querybuilder documentation-

```
$builder->orderBy("name");
```

The documentation doesn't show any way of adding ASC/DESC with the order by clause.

I tried to do something like-

```
$fileQueryBuilder->orderBy("$orderByColumnName","$sort");
```

where **$orderByColumnName** has column name and **$sort** has either ASC or DESC, but I get the error:

> Uncaught BadMethodCallException: Wrong number of parameters

because orderBy expects only one parameter.

I also tried doing

```
$orderOrder = $orderByColumnName . $sort;
$fileQueryBuilder->orderBy("orderOrder");
```

But then it takes the name of column and ASC/DESC together in one variable, and error shows that it's an

> unavailable field in the table

Comment: Submit your Full Query

Comment: @manishk please accept the best solution that solved your issue.

Comment: @mickmackusa I solved it myself, I have it on the comments of the answer posted by Pickle.

Comment: Then mark your own answer with the green tick.  All Stackoverflow pages deserve a system recognized resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a few permutations, I got it to work when I used the following-

```
$fileQueryBuilder->orderBy($orderByColumnName. ' ' .$sort);
```

(using a space between $orderByColumnName and $sort)

Answer (score 1):

The order by parameter can include the sort direction, so you want to do:

```
$builder->orderBy('name DESC');
```

Comment: I tried this- 
$fileQueryBuilder->orderBy("$orderByColumnName $sort");
Doesn't work.

Comment: What does "$orderByColumnName $sort" get rendered to as a string?  What does "Doesn't work" mean?  Do you get an exception?  Does the query run but the results aren't what you expect?  Do you have the ability to see what the query looks like that the database actually sees?

Comment: Sorry about that. When i used "$orderByColumnName $sort" , it gave an error 'incorrect field'; because it was taking 'name ASC' as the field name.
After a few permutations, I got it to work when I used this- 

$fileQueryBuilder->orderBy($orderByColumnName. ' ' .$sort);

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes, and it also require a space in order to work correctly.

```
$orderOrder = $orderByColumnName . ' ' . $sort;
$fileQueryBuilder->orderBy($orderOrder);
```